# Find all workflows and infopaths on a given Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow, infopath

I'm migrating Sharepoint 2013 to SPO and want to get a list of all workflows and infopaths for a given source and destination site. The problem is that I'm not the farm admin. I have admin rights only for certain sites of the collection. I tried to modify some of the examples I found here on stackexchange to no avail. My understanding is that I have to use the CSOM model. Is this correct and is it possible at all to do this since I read that CSOM is with limited abilities compared to the SSOM with snap ins.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that using CSOM. However before migrating you can use SMAT tool to assess your current farm. It provides lot of details such as workflow, sites, sizes etc.

This is also best practice to assess your current farm before migrating.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/overview-of-the-sharepoint-migration-assessment-tool

Comment: As I can see SMAT should be run on the server itself. I don't have admin rights to the farm  or physical access.

Comment: Yes it should be run from the server. You can ask the SharePoint administrator to run it and give you the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the CTO at Kudzu Software, so the following is a bit of product pitch.

[Kudzu](https://kudzusoftware.com) provides a totally free tool ([the FORMulator](https://formulator.kudzusoftware.com)) that can scan on-premises or M365 SharePoint instances for InoPath forms. It additionally opens up the forms and analyzes them to calculate complexity and portability scores.  That along with usage information can be used to plan InfoPath replacement initiatives. There's a calculator that you can use to estimate effort and get some idea of how much you could save with our automation-assisted migration platform.